# Estructura de subdominios que alojen páginas en WP con contenido diferente basadas en países. Ej: https://www.apple.com/es/

Tags: wordpress

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en Wordpress en el que necesito crear una estructura de subdominios que alojen páginas con contenido diferente basadas en países, de manera que si alguien entra desde España por ejemplo el dominio sería "www.midominio.com/es/" o si por ejemplo es desde USA pues sería "www.midominio.com/us/".

Cada página sería diferente. Mi hosting me permite crear subdominios con la estructura "www.subdominio1.midominio.com", pero eso no es lo que busco, necesitaría la estructura anteriormente nombrada.

Sinceramente no sé ni por donde empezar a realizar esta estructura ni como hacer esas redirecciones por IP. Mi hosting de confianza es Hostinger.

Alguien podría echarme una manita??

Comment: Investiga sobre WordPress Multisite, te permite crear test.dominio.com o dominio.com/test, si no quieres tener sitios diferentes puedes probar con complementos de traducción como WPML que igual permite generar urls tipo /es con diferente idioma

Comment: Importante, multisite es para tener varios sitios y administrarlos todos desde un wordpress, mientras que WPML es mas que todo para tener un solo sitio en diferentes idiomas pero diferenciados por url

Comment: Hola. La pregunta no es clara. Hablas de múltiples dominios, cuando el dominio es siempre el mismo: `midominio.com`. Para hablar de múltiples dominios tendrías que tener algo como `midominio.es`, `midominio.it`, `midominio.fr`, etc. Es importante que aclares ese aspecto fundamental en tu pregunta.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias Jefferzon Bol, voy a mirar ese Wordpress Multisite. Pero pensaba que era algo que podría realizar a través del Hosting, ya que este, si me permite realizar subdominios pero con el formato "subdominio1.dominio1.com" y ese no me vale

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: WordPress multisite lo hace casi que de forma automatica, pero tambien lo puedes hacer de forma manual, el problema es que de forma manual debes de instalar wordpress por cada subdominio, mientras que con multisite no, ademas, debes de configurar en tus dns tu dominio como dominio wildcard o dominio comodin, de esa forma podras crear subdominios sin necesidad de configurar dns para cada subdominio.

Comment: ahora, si quieres como crear algo tipo dominio.com/es/ solo debes ir a la carpeta principal de tu instalación y crear la carpeta /es y poner ahi el contenido o la instalación de wordpress que quieras usar, basta con ingresar con dominio.com/es, como es una estructura de carpetas no necesitas configurar subdominios para eso